# Is it possible a Search Engine Friendly Redirct with Interface page?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

I want to redirect page like: `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?id=1` to `http://www.mysite.com/the-real-name.htm` but I don’t have the-real-name in first url then I should get it from db.

I made an interface page then I redirected page `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?id=1` to it and I fetched the-real-name (with id parameter in url) from db then I redirected page to `http://www.mysite.com/the-real-name.htm` with PHP Header function.

Is this process search engine friendly?

Which page will be indexed with search engine crawler? Interface page or `http://www.mysite.com/the-real-name.htm` ?

Which is the best solution for indexing `http://www.mysite.com/the-real-name.htm` ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to tell the search engine that the final URL is "the URL", you need to do a **permanent redirect**. The HTTP status code is `301`.

```
header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/the-real-name.htm', true, 301);
```

For the first redirect, you need to do a **temporary redirect**. The HTTP status code is `302`.

```
header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?id=1', true, 302);
```

Keep in mind that it's good practice to not only send headers back for redirects, but a HTTP/HTML BODY as well that is shipping human readable information where the new location is. Redirects are not to be expected to be automatically performed by the client.

### Different ways to implement

Depending on the system you work on, setting a HTTP status header with PHP might differ. The code above is for a working PHP version. Stick to latest. However, if you can not and the server integration is broken you might to push a bit the limits and force around a bit:

```
# Manually sending the HTTP 1/1 status line header - PHP does this nowadays, so normally not needed. But if you need it, ensure it's the first header you send.
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); 
# Same here, but some CGI/FCGI+PHP implementations require you to set the Status header as well manually. Normally not needed.
header ('Status: 301'); 
# Set the Location header and status: (you will always need this)
header ('Location: http://www.mysite.com/the-real-name.htm', true, 301);
```

Always check if your script sends the correct headers by requesting it with a tool that is able to display the response headers not performing the redirect automatically, like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/):

```
$ curl -i "http://www.mysite.com/index.php?id=1"
```

Otherwise it takes a little long to wait for google to reflect the changes only for you to realize that you made some error.

Comment: Thanks a lot hakre, you surprised me with your very quick reply. with this solution will search engines like google index http://www.mysite.com/the-real-name.htm instead of http://www.mysite.com/index.php?id=1 which is indexed and has a good rank? thanks dude

Comment: @Alich: Haha. Okay I read a little doubt in there. For the log: Yes google indexes the 301 redirected location. At least this is common since I know google. However it's always possible that they change this from one moment to the other. But, before you can start to whine about that, the wave of outcry would have started already. You wouldn't be the only one who would be affected. Next to that most SEO practitioners would start a massive-aggressive reaction to that. So well, I'm sure you can be much more relaxed with this issue and the risk implementing my suggestions should be low for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

When redirecting also set a 301 header and the search engines will know what to to from there.

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: '.$location);
```

Comment: The HTTP status code can be set with the third parameter of [`header()`](http://php.net/function.header)

Answer (score 1):

If the relationship *cannot change*, use a permanent redirect [as hakre suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321615/is-it-possible-a-search-engine-friendly-redirct-with-interface-page/6321624#6321624) (a 301 status code). Otherwise, if that same `id` value might point somewhere else in the future, use a temporary redirect.

In either case, if the canonical (official, main, primary) URL is "http://www.mysite.com/the-real-name.htm", you can tell search engines that with a [canonical meta tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) in the page's `head` section:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/the-real-name.htm" />
```

Comment: Or with a sitemap file I think.